# controller for view not working codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two views ie, `views/pages/home.php` and `views/pages/search_result.php`. I have a controller to load this views ie, `controllers/Pages.php`. And also i have one more folder inside view ie, `views/templates/header.php` and `views/templates/footer.php`

When i am pointing the browser to `http://localhost/codeigniter/home` everything working perfect.

But the problem is when i am pointing the browser to `http://localhost/codeigniter/search_result`, the view `footer.php` is also showing. Actually am not given anything inside `search_result.php`

My controller code is,

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function home($page = 'home')
    {
        //code to show home.php (http://localhost/codeigniter/home)
        if (!file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }
       else
       {
            $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
       }
    }

    public function search_result($page = 'search_result') {
        //code to show search_result.php (http://localhost/codeigniter/search_result)
    }

}
```

Inside `search_result` function i didn't given any code and while am pointing to `http://localhost/codeigniter/search_result` the footer from function `home` is showing ie, `$this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);`

What am doing wrong. Is there any solution to solve this issue. I am beginner in codeigniter.

Comment: if this address http://localhost/codeigniter/home calls the Pages controller, then there is probably some code in application/config/routes.php that you should look at, because routes is the typical way you would call a controller name different then the url address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply try this

```
public function home()
{
    //code to show home.php (http://localhost/codeigniter/home)
    if (!file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/home.php'))
    {
        // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
        show_404();
    }
   else
   {
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/Home', $data); # changed 
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
   }
}
```

Comment: above code is working for `home.php`. but i want to display the second page `search_reult.php`